# iPhone UDP broadcast and response

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sockets, udp

I need to send out a UDP broadcast from an iPhone, and then listen for a UDP response with a timeout period.  I have found Apple's [UDPEcho example](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/UDPEcho/Introduction/Intro.html) but I am not sure if it's what I need.  Also found [this example](http://splinter.com.au/sending-a-udp-broadcast-packet-in-c-objective) to send but not receive.  Basically, I need to do something simple like this:

```
//send the broadcast
SendUDP("255.255.255.255", targetPort, myData);
//A blocking call to get the data.  Timeout value will be short, 2 seconds at most
//An asynchronous option is ok, if it's necessary.
Response = GetFirstUDPResponse(receptionPort, timeoutValue);

//process the response
if(Response == null)
  //we timed out
else
  //process response
```

I'm hoping for a simple solution where I don't have to reinvent the wheel.  I appreciate any advice on the best strategy to implement this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [cocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) which is easier to use than apple native classes.
It support UDP with AsyncUdpSocket class.

> AsyncUdpSocket is a UDP/IP socket networking library that wraps
>   CFSocket. It works almost exactly like the TCP version, but is
>   designed specifically for UDP. This includes queued non-blocking
>   send/receive operations, full delegate support, run-loop based,
>   self-contained class, and support for IPv4 and IPv6

Comment: Thanks, it was easy.  I provided most of my code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790149/little-problem-with-asyncudpsocket-receiving-data-after-connecting-to-broadcast-i/7682688#7682688

Answer (score 5):

I'd put 'recvfrom' on another thread using grand central dispatch, like this:

```
// Use grand central dispatch so we don't block the interface
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

    recvfrom(...) // Receive with a 2s timeout

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // The main thread stuff goes here

        if (received ok) {
            [self receivedData:some data];
        } else {
            [self timedOut];
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: One thing though, you may want to make sure you're listening (ie recvfrom) before you send the broadcast packet, otherwise a response may come back in the small time gap between sending and listening. However, to do this, you must bind your ephemeral port first.

Comment: i'm curious about your receive with a 2s timeout part. how do you implement this?