# Cannot received UDP packet on Iphone w/ AsyncUdpSocket

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, udp, packet

Hi guys im working on a project at school and I got a problem, I'm able to send UDP packet to different adress but I can't read UDP packet sent to my iPhone, after receiving an UDP packet I want the data to appear in a label, im doing something wrong but I dont know what.....my code :

```
- (BOOL)onUdpSocket:(AsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag fromHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
    NSLog(@"Incoming data");

    [sock receiveWithTimeout:1 tag:0];
    NSString *receiveddata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
  //  NSString *receiveddata = data ;
    self.testudp.text = receiveddata;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Please check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/q/4215149/2315974

Comment: still doesnt work !!! :(

Comment: one more thing, Is the above method called on the main thread ?

Comment: no, its called in my viewcontroller whit my senddata

Answer (score 0):

thats the changes I've made :

```
AsyncUdpSocket *udpsocket;
udpsocket = [[AsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
[udpsocket enableBroadcast:YES error:nil];
[udpsocket bindToPort:1234 error:nil];
[udpsocket receiveWithTimeout:-1 tag:0];

- (BOOL)onUdpSocket:(AsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data withTag:(long)tag fromHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port{
    NSLog(@"received data");
    NSString *receiveddata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    _testudp.text = receiveddata;
```

Comment: _testudp isn't a UILabel ?

Comment: yes its a label, but every things work now, the thing is that I never open the socket